# Undefined Property With the property filled at all alert points

Tags: angular, typescript

So a-cording to the console I cant route to the dashboard after a login because the surname property is undefined but on my alerts i can see it filled correctly at all times

```
login(surName: string, passWord){    
    const name = this.members.find( x => x.surname === surName)
    const pass = this.members.find( x => x.password === passWord)
    if(name && pass){
      for (const element of this.members) {
        if(element.surname === surName){
            alert(element.surname + surName);
            this.persist.setPersistence(surName, element.color);
            alert("You are Logged in" + element.surname + element.color);
            this.router.navigate(['/dashbaord']);
            return;
        }
    }
    }else{
      alert("User Details are incorrect please make sure your username and password is correct");
  }
}
```

I can check at any point from the data being entered to the login being pressed to the value being passed into the set function this is where the error happens but I can see the value so I dont know whats happening

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Persistance} from '../Persistance/persistance.model'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersistService {
  persist: Persistance;
  constructor() { }

  setPersistence(surname : string, color: string){
    alert(surname);
    this.persist.surname = surname;
    this.persist.color = color;
  }
}
```

The Error:

```
core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'surname' of undefined
```

I can see the property defined at all points where its being assigned or used so i dont really get whats happening here

Comment: I'm not sure why the error is happening (something in the `@Injectable`) but I think you are misinterpreting the error message.  It is saying that `this.persist` is `undefined`, therefore you cannot treat it as an object and set a property on it.

Comment: Your Persistance object isn't initialized. It's only declared but no initial value has been assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```js
persist: Persistance = {};
```

should do the trick. Your object hasn't been initialized yet hence you can't assign values to any of its properties.

Comment: So with this, This works yes if my Properties are optional.. So would u care to expand and tell me weather.. For a persistent  constant stream of that data 

The optional property with a blank initialise as per. your answer is better or is it better to just do

```persist: Persistance = new Persistance();```

Comment: That depends on whether `Persistance` is an interface or a class. If it's a class, you'll want to initialize it as `persist: Persistance = new Persistance();`. If not, then you go with the solution I posted.

Comment: It is a class, Thank you for Expanding